# IOS : log of GPS access

Tags: ios, gps, core-location

Is there a way to access or find out when an app uses GPS? To be specific, in the new iMessage update there is a way to always send your location to someone indefinitely but you can never know when that person is actually looking at your location. So is there any information about this in core location or is it not possible to obtain?

In other words: Can I see when my stalker is looking at my location?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable in the ios settings menu that whenever an (any)  application uses GPS, a violett arrow symbol is displayed in the status bar of the phone (top most, near the battery symbol) Enable via Settings->DataProtection->LocationServices->Sytem Services->Enable Status Bar Symbol

Further there is a menu "Settings->DataProtection->LocationServices" 
which list all Apps that use GPS. You can disable the location service for each app separately. Look if you find there under "System services" an entry for iMessage.

Of course you cannot see whether a person on a remote device reads your messages, if that App does not support a "messages was read" feature.

So you can try to disab